# Identifying unrealistic traits of this exoplanet. There are a few obvious ones, but I can't find them all. Help!

Tags: homework-and-exercises

I need to find the inaccuracies of this computer generated picture, the picture shows a non existent exoplanet. I need to identify the unrealistic features of the planet and its surroundings and write an essay on some of them.

The image is located here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXrPy.jpg

Could you help point out some of these innacuracies?

Comment: You should at least tell us what you've thought about so far, rather than just asking people to find things for you.

Comment: Sorry, Benjamin, but as far as I can tell, this question is really about geology. Perhaps it has a bit to do with astronomy but there is very little physics in it, and thus I don't believe it's on topic here.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting Homework type exercise - I wonder which Institution is setting this as a physics question?

Anyway here are some thoughts:

1) How many Suns are in this system? Where are they located and what shadows do they cast?

2) The 3 Body Gravitational problem may have some relevance here. (Look it up if you wonder why.)

3) What is your view on how weathering works? There is water here, clouds - so do all the landscapes look appropriately weathered?

4) What forms Jupiter's cloud belts? Why do I even ask this?

Enough for now.

Comment: Its for a high-school course called Earth and Space Science. Thanks for the thoughts, I will definitely look into what forms Jupiter's belts. The water I am not sure about, I think my teacher may have told us that It was another compound in Liquid form.